# C program bad code confusion (compare values)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, min, function-definition

Just trying to compare two values in C, and find the smaller value. Accidently did it in a really bad style, but I don't understand why C still let it run... the program didn't include the branch that two values are equal. But when it's given two equal values, it gives the program gives out the same value... may I ask what did C complier do? Thank you!
(the example below returns 3...)

```
int min(int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3, b = 3;
    printf("%d", min(a,b));
}

int min(int x, int y)
{
    if(x > y)
    return y;
}
    else if(x < y)
{
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Not returning a value in a function that is defined to do so results in Undefined Behaviour. It means the end result is unpredictable. The compiler is not required to flag all undefined behaviours. But many compilers will give a warning for such errors. May need to turn up the warnings level on your compiler to see all of the warnings.

Comment: No, the compiler did not let this program run because there are obvious syntax errors. If you got some other source code running than the one you posted here, then post that source code instead.

Comment: @kaylum: Re “Not returning a value in a function that is defined to do so results in Undefined Behaviour”: Not returning a value does not cause undefined behavior. Using the value of a function that has not returned a value has undefined behavior. Not returning a value is deliberately permitted by the C standard because there are functions that sometimes return a value and sometimes do not, such as a function that gets or sets a stored setting, as selected by its arguments.

Comment: `gcc` does not compile such code. What's the name of your compiler?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... It was late when I posted... got the curly bracket messed up... but @kaylum explained what was the reason, as well as the other answer who helped me fixed the confusion. Thanks you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

> Accidently did it in a really bad style, but I don't understand why C
> still let it run..

The program should not compile because this code

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    if(x > y)
    return y;
}
    else if(x < y)
{
    return x;
}
```

is syntactically incorrect.

This else statement

```
    else if(x < y)
{
    return x;
}
```

is placed outside any function including `min`.

It seems you mean

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    if(x > y)
    {
        return y;
    }
    else if(x < y)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

> But when it's given two equal values, it gives the program gives out
> the same value... may I ask what did C complier do?

The program has undefined behavior because the function `min` returns nothing when its two arguments are equal each other.

From the C Standard (6.9.1 Function definitions)

> 12 If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of
> the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

It should be defined for example the following way

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the code posted though - easy enough to get fooled by the weird brace placement.

Comment: oh yes! Thank you for the correction and the resource :)